# How to write setFieldValue setFieldTouched functions for Dropdown from "semantic-ui-react" as Formik props

Tags: reactjs, dropdown, formik, semantic-ui-react

Where can I find or download or import examples of setFieldValue setFieldTouched functions? Do I have to write them myself? They are required as props. I cannot find any examples of them

```
export const DiagnosisSelection = ({
  diagnoses,
  setFieldValue,
  setFieldTouched
}: {
  diagnoses: DiagnosisEntry[];
  setFieldValue: FormikProps<{ diagnosisCodes: string[] }>["setFieldValue"];
  setFieldTouched: FormikProps<{ diagnosisCodes: string[] }>["setFieldTouched"];
}) => {
  const field = "diagnosisCodes";
  const onChange = (
    _event: React.SyntheticEvent<HTMLElement, Event>,
    data: DropdownProps
  ) => {
    setFieldTouched(field, true);
    setFieldValue(field, data.value);
  };

  const stateOptions = diagnoses.map(diagnosis => ({
    key: diagnosis.code,
    text: `${diagnosis.name} (${diagnosis.code})`,
    value: diagnosis.code
  }));

  return (
    <Form.Field>
      <label>Diagnoses</label>
      <Dropdown
        fluid
        multiple
        search
        selection
        options={stateOptions}
        onChange={onChange}
      />
      <ErrorMessage name={field} />
    </Form.Field>
  );
};
```